# SFMC error when creating custom activity: A custom activity or entry source failed validation

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I am creating a custom activity and use [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/creating-activities.html) guide for it. However when I try to use my activity in Journey Builder, I get this error:

"A custom activity or entry source failed validation. Check to ensure that the activity or entry source publishes to a valid endpoint."

config.json gets created dynamically and uses Heroku endpoints:

```
module.exports = function configJSON() {
    return {
        workflowApiVersion: "1.1",
        metaData: {
            icon: "images/icon.svg",
            category: "custom"
        },
        type: "REST",
        lang: {
            "en-US": {
                name: "Custom activity",
                description: "A custom activity."
            }
        },
        arguments: {
            execute: {
                inArguments: [],
                outArguments: [],
                timeout: 100000,
                retryCount: 1,
                retryDelay: 10000,
                concurrentRequests: 5,
                url: `https://${process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME}.herokuapp.com/execute`,
                verb: "POST",
                format: "JSON",
                body: "",
                header: "",
                useJwt: true
            }
        },
        configurationArguments: {
            save: {
                url: `https://${process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME}.herokuapp.com/save`,
                verb: "POST",
                body: "",
                header: "",
                useJwt: true
            },
            publish: {
                url: `https://${process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME}.herokuapp.com/publish`,
                verb: "POST",
                body: "",
                header: "",
                useJwt: true
            },
            validate: {
                url: `https://${process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME}.herokuapp.com/validate`,
                verb: "POST",
                format: "JSON",
                body: "",
                header: "",
                useJwt: true
            }
        },
        userInterfaces: {
            configModal: {
                height: 200,
                width: 500,
                fullscreen: true
            }
        },
        schema: {
            arguments: {
                execute: {
                    inArguments: [],
                    outArguments: []
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The function that calls configJSON():

```
router.get('/config.json', function (req, res) {
    return res.status(200).json(configJSON());
});

module.exports = router;
```

activity.js that handles the activity lifecycle:

```
function execute(req, res) {
    verifyJwt(req.body, process.env.JWT, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) return res.status(401).end();
        res.status(200).send({
            status: 'ok',
        });
    });
}

function validate(req, res) {
    verifyJwt(req.body, process.env.JWT, err => {
        if (err) return res.status(401).end();
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
        });
    });
}

router.post('/execute', execute);
router.post(/\/(save|publish|validate)/, validate);
router.get(/\/(save|publish|validate)/, validate);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Check this hope this helps to debug, https://github.com/bhanuatsfdc/SFMC

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have found the problem. I forgot to actually call the activity lifecycle methods in my server.js file.